# SSH windows to vmware

Tags: networking, ssh, vmware-player

I have a VMWare Player running a

> SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64) VERSION = 10 PATCHLEVEL = 1

All works fine execpt that I cannot connect from the windows host to the image.

From putty I get the error message:

> Network error: Software caused connection abort

From /var/log/messages

> Jan 15 03:45:55 tdx sshd[4492]: fatal: Timeout before authentication for 192.168.11.150

The VMWare player network adapter is setup as "Bridged" and has a static IP assigned through DHCP

nslookup of the client and vmware image names works both ways.

Comment: What is your `LoginGraceTime` set to in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?  (in the VM of course). Also, since it is bridged, can you try SSHing into  it from another machine?

Answer (score 0):

Found an error in the ' c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts'. The hostname had several entries for the vmware image, and the "actual" hostname was not the first in the list, that is the one registred in the DHCPd. After I moved it to the first it works.